# Compare previous file size with the current filesize and flag

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-os

I have a bash script which loops through all YAML files in the `yaml` directory, executing a python script. This python scripts simply prints out if the JSON file exists along with its file size as well as YAML file existing.

Essentially, I am trying to save the file size of the last run and compare this with the filesize of the current run. If the difference of the filesize is more than 50% , this will flag the JSON file with a log or print statement. I have been looking at the python `os` module to use the following function to store the last access time of the file

```
def getatime(filename):
    """Return the last access time of a file, reported by os.stat()."""
    return os.stat(filename).st_atime
```

I can save the last access time in a variable
I can also save the file size in a variable

Would I need to create a conditional statement and compare the last run file size with the current run file size?

Answer (score 0):

No, a conditional statement is not necessarily.

In order to compare the previous file size with the current file size you need to use a comparison operator (`<`, `>=`, etc). Assuming you read the previous size  from some file into a dictionary `sz` that maps path names to file sizes, you can do the comparison, for some file name stored in the variable `file_name` as follows:

```
sz[file_name] < os.path.getsize(file_name)
```

You will quite often see this in a conditional statement:

```
if sz[file_name] < os.path.getsize(file_name):
    print('size has increased')
```

but that is not the only way to get the message printed. You could e.g. also use:

```
try:
    assert sz[file_name] < os.path.getsize(file_name)
    print('size has increased')
except AssertionError:
    pass
```

or:

```
while sz[file_name] < os.path.getsize(file_name):
    print('size has increased')
    break
```

All having the same effect.